# flutter websocket cannot send bytebuffer in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, websocket, bytebuffer

My flutter app need to send data type [bytebuffer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html) from client to sever via websocket. But [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel) is not support send data type bytebuffer or number.

Are there any library support send bytebuffer via websocket in flutter app?

Comment: Think that your app needs to sent bytes. No buffers or any other data type.

Comment: with `websocket` you can only send either raw binary data or `String`, nothing more

Comment: @pskink raw binary data is bytebuffer??? what data type of binary data? not Uint8list, i think Uint8list is an array

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html - it is `List<int>` - in other words: binary data

Comment: @pskink My fault, i think List<int> not a binary type. thank you very much.